# Is the same '#!/usr/bin/env bash' than #!/bin/bash

Tags: bash, scripts, environment

Simple question, is the same ? Vim autocomplete me when write `bash` + `tab`  =>  `#!/usr/bin/env bash` but I usually watch `#!/bin/bash` in every script. So..

Comment: Another similar post on Stack Overflow: [Why is #!/usr/bin/env bash superior to #!/bin/bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21612980/4464570)

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR:

Use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

---

Long answer:

Nope, they are not identical. The first form (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`) [is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/16886597), as it will work when Bash is in your path, but isn't in `/bin`. Often, both will work. However, if your script runs on a system where `/bin/bash` isn't Bash (or isn't a symlink to it), then `#!/bin/bash` won't work as it isn't in that location, but `#!/usr/bin/env bash` will.

`env` looks up a command in your path, so if Bash is in your path but not in `/bin`, then you need to use `env`. Practically, because a decent amount of scripts don't use `env`, OS's tend to make `/bin/bash` either Bash or a symlink to it. Note that [there is a small chance `env` won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52860837/16886597) if you have using some old system, but on any reasonably modern OS (Debian, Ubuntu, Arch, Fedora, etc.) it is best to use `env`.

Comment: This recommendation is preposterous. You can't make recommendation that works in every case without knowing the context. For example system scripts must use `/bin/bash` because they have to work, and they're guaranteed to work with `/bin/bash` whereas the user environment may use a differnet bash version or may not have it at all. Another case is when the script is owned by `root` and has the setuid bit. This case is a huge security concern when using `env` but not a problem when using `/bin/bash`

Comment: The concern about setuid makes sense - it wasn’t something I considered. Consider either suggesting an edit to my answer explaining the pitfalls of doing it this way and why having the actual path can be better. If you’d prefer to write your own answer, you could on the question this is a dupe of (although check to ensure existing answers don’t include that)